# Priority ordered combinations of a list

Tags: python, list, combinations

First of all, all possible combinations of a list should be generated. It is straightforward problem - thanks to *itertools.combinations*. Then, the combinations must be ordered according to the following priorities: first element of the original list has the highest priority, second has the second priority and so on. Note that any grouping of lower priorities cannot be higher than any higher priority.
Trivial example:

```
input = ['A', 'B']
output = [['A', 'B'], ['A'], ['B']]
```

3 elements example:

```
input = ['A', 'B', 'C']
output = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['B'], ['C']]
```

Question: Given a list of any elements, how to find the list of all possible combinations ordered by priorities as described above?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the question is clear IMO, they have several examples of inputs and outputs and they thought about using itertools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an element to a list always increases priority. We can maintain a list of lists and recursively add worst elements first to get the desired order.

```
cs = ["A", "B", "C"]


def subsets(xs):
    res = [[]]
    for x in xs[::-1]:
        res = [[x] + r for r in res] + res

    return res[:-1]


# [["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "B"], ["A", "C"], ["A"], ["B", "C"], ["B"], ["C"]]
```

During the execution, `res` looks as follows:

```
[[]]
[["C"],[]]
[["B","C"],["B"],["C"],[]]
...
```

Alternatively, you can rely on `itertools.product` to get a lazy solution.

```
from itertools import product


def lazy_subsets(xs):
    for ix in product(*([[True, False]] * len(xs))):
        yield [x for x, b in zip(xs, ix) if b]


res = list(lazy_subsets(cs))[:-1]
```

Here, each `ix` is a list of `bool`s that is used as a boolean mask to filter `xs`. The order in which `product` yields `ix`'s coincides with the order on subsets of `xs` that gives priorities to initial elements.

Comment: I would be happy to hear how to improve this answer.

Comment: like your itertools.product solution - really concise...

Comment: Upvoted! It looks very "pythonic".

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the combinations by a priority function which is defined as a sorted list of original indices of elements of a combination (lower index means higher priority) padded by infinities at the end (since we want to give higher length combinations a chance against lower length combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
index = {l: i for i, l in enumerate(lst)}

def priority(c):
    return sorted([index[x] for x in c]) + [float('inf')] * (len(lst) - len(c))


result = sorted([c for i in range(1, len(lst) + 1) for c in combinations(lst, i)], key=priority)
print(result)
# [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A',), ('B', 'C'), ('B',), ('C',)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A little clunky, but this works using itertools.combinations...

```
import itertools

def iter(string):
    raw_result = []
    result = []
    for i in range(len(string), -1, -1):
        for y in itertools.combinations(string, i):
            if len(y) > 0:
                raw_result.append(list(y))
    for s in string:
        for bit in raw_result:
            if s == bit[0]:
                result.append(bit)
    return result
print(iter('ABCD'))
```